# How to Display name of image using onclick and this.title

Tags: javascript

My assignment is to display the image name on an image using onclick.

I need to add an onClick handler to set the title property of the image to My New Title(Hint You can access the image title using this.title)

This is my code,

```
<img src="tick1.gif" alt="tick1" onClick="setimagename(My New Title)';" />
```

my instructor is not being much help as I keep asking what I'm missing but instead answers something else

I know this is something simple, but I just cannot get it to work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What you have given is `HTML` part, where is `setimagename` function?

Comment: th only thing I can suggest to you - read some html tutorial

Comment: what does your instructor say?

Comment: Here is the assignment.                                                                           Starting with Listing 2.4, remove the onMouseOver and onMouseOut handlers from the <img> element. Instead, add an onClick handler to set the title property of the image to My New Title. [Hint: You can access the image title using this.title.]

Here is the Code (2.5)    '<img src="tick.gif" alt="tick" onmouseover="this.src='tick2.gif';"
onmouseout="this.src='tick.gif';" />' Instructor says to simply copy the line above and replace the onmouseover w/ onclick which I have done but still wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is more simple. You only need minor alterations to what is provided in the text. You cannot have an alt="" attribute and expect JavaScript to fire a change directed at 'title'. You must apply a title attribute before you can alter one.

```
     <img src =" tick.gif" title="Click me and watch me change!!" onclick="this.title='New Image Title!!!';"/>
```

alt="" and title="" are pretty much the same thing. Remove the alt="" to reduce redundancy and replace with title="".

Once you have done this, hover over your image and wait a moment for the title to appear, then click and hold more a moment and you will see the title appear with your new code.

Good Luck in your JavaScript course.

Answer (score 0):

Is hard to diagnose without seeing the `setimagename` code but probably the issue is that you are missing quotes in the string My New Title that you are passing as argument:

```
<img src="tick1.gif" alt="tick1" onclick="setimagename('My New Title');" />
```

Also notice in your code that when the function is called you have ' char which will cause you another syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="tick1.gif" alt="tick1" onClick="this.title='My New Title'" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You are passing a `String` on a `function` you should put a `quote` on it.

onClick="setimagename('My New Title');"

Comment: why not `onClick="this.title='My New Title'"` ?

Comment: can you also display your code on your function `setimagename` maybe there's an error on that.

Comment: @CarlosG, what is expected behavior? What do you mean by 'title'?

Comment: @msangel the point of the excercise is to click on the image and display the title (This is my new title)

Comment: @CarlosG, where the 'title' should appear? You have only image here, nothing else. And 'image' display only images, nothing else. So if you want to print some text somewhere, the target for this text is definitly not image.

Answer (score -1):

**`<img src="tick1.gif" alt="tick1" onClick="setimagename('My New Title');" />`**

or

bind click event in script.